# select_tag helper with grouped_options_for_select order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I have this in my model:

```
LOCATION_IN_UK = {'England' => [['Berkshire', 1],['Cambridgeshire',2],['Cheshire',3]], 'Scotland' => [['Dumfries and Galloway',4],['Fife',5],['Lothian',6]], 'Others' => [['Outside UK',7]]}
```

And this is in the view:

```
<%= select_tag :location, grouped_options_for_select(Location::LOCATION_IN_UK), :id => 'location-dropdown' %>
```

This code generate following html:

```
<select id="location-dropdown" name="location">
  <optgroup label="England">
    <option value="1">Berkshire</option> 
    <option value="2">Cambridgeshire</option> 
    <option value="3">Cheshire</option></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Others">
    <option value="7">Outside UK</option></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Scotland">
    <option value="4">Dumfries and Galloway</option> 
    <option value="5">Fife</option> 
    <option value="6">Lothian</option></optgroup>
</select>
```

**1.** How to skip alphabetical sort order. I want elements locate exactly as in the hash LOCATION_IN_UK.
**2.** How to insert prompt into this? `:prompt => 'Please select'` Doesn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your prompt question, prompt is not a hash, it is the third parameter of the method call.  So you would do:

```
 <%= select_tag :location, grouped_options_for_select(LOCATIONS_IN_UK, nil, "Please Select"), :id => 'location-dropdown' %>
```

And looking at the source code, it seems there is no way to skip the sorting.  You could write your own helper method though.  Here is the source

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb, line 449
      def grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, selected_key = nil, prompt = nil)
        body = ''
        body << content_tag(:option, prompt, { :value => "" }, true) if prompt

        grouped_options = grouped_options.sort if grouped_options.is_a?(Hash)

        grouped_options.each do |group|
          body << content_tag(:optgroup, options_for_select(group[1], selected_key), :label => group[0])
        end

        body.html_safe
      end
```

You could modify/override that method, but that may break if you are using this function elsewhere, which is why I would suggest you put the following in your application_helper.

```
def unsorted_grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, selected_key = nil, prompt = nil)
  body = ''
  body << content_tag(:option, prompt, { :value => "" }, true) if prompt

  ##Remove sort
  #grouped_options = grouped_options.sort if grouped_options.is_a?(Hash)

  grouped_options.each do |group|
    body << content_tag(:optgroup, options_for_select(group[1], selected_key), :label => group[0])
  end

  body.html_safe
end
```

You can then call unsorted_grouped_options_for_select and it should work.

```
 <%= select_tag :location, unsorted_grouped_options_for_select(LOCATION::LOCATION_IN_UK, nil, "Please Select"), :id => 'location-dropdown' %>
```

Comment: sorry, this is doesnt work. says wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) to me. i try to delete nil, all work, but prompt option doesnt appears

Comment: What version of rails are you on?  Also, see my edits, if you use my 2nd function then it should work.

Comment: seems like prompt doesnt work with select_tag, i wrap it into a form, and call as f.select, and now works fine. Going to look at the order problem. Thanks!

Comment: prompt is not a property of select tag, it is a property of grouped_options_for_select.  In any case, I recommend you look at my edits which should solve both problems.  I have tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You can solve this by using the array version instead of hashes since it only orders it if it is_a?(Hash).
See the docs for the format: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select

Comment: This is way better than overriding the select_tag helper. Should be upvoted